# Loop through JSON with VBScript

Tags: json, vbscript

I need to parse the JSON returned from an API in VBScript. I have the code that sends the request to the API and gets the response (this code can be provided). I only need the code that parses through the records of the JSON returned by the API and make it available. I need to know the content of each field from the JSON, and when each record starts and ends, so that each record can be stored in a database (database store code not needed).

The JSON model schema is like so:

```json
{
  "name": string
  "id": int
  "birth": date
}
```

If you have your own JSON parsing library, it can be useful. I am using [this](http://demon.tw/my-work/vbs-json.html) (it can be provided).

The code I have so far is like this:

```vb
Set objHTTP = Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
objHTTP.open "GET", "http://localhost/website/api.asp", False
'Some headers:
objHTTP.setRequestHeader "CustomerAccountId", "{my_account_id}" 
objHTTP.setRequestHeader "CustomerId", "{my_customer_id}"
objHTTP.setRequestHeader "DeveloperToken", "{my_API_access_Key}"
objHTTP.setRequestHeader "Password", "{my_password}"
objHTTP.setRequestHeader "UserName", "{my_user_name}"
objHTTP.send ""

'Error treatment:
If objHTTP.Status >= 400 And objHTTP.Status <= 599 Then
   Response.write "Error Occurred : " & objHTTP.status & " - " & objHTTP.statusText
   Response.end
Else
   Response.write "Success : " & objHTTP.status & " - " & objHTTP.ResponseText
   Response.end
End If

str = objHTTP.responseText
Set o = json.Decode(str)
'I need the rest of the code here!
```

Comment: The [parser](http://demon.tw/my-work/vbs-json.html) returns either object or array. For this case I guess that's array (I didn't see the entire JSON though). Have you tried `For Each ... Next` to loop through array elements?

Comment: I don't see a question here other than "can sombody please write code for me?", which would be off-topic. For help with non-working code: show the non-working code and explain, what exactly isn't working. Include all error messages you're getting. Also, there's no `response.write` in plain VBScript. Is this ASP?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are using Classic ASP. That means you can easily run JScript instead of VBScript.

And *that* means you can use [a proper JSON parser](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js) and easy syntax to access the resulting object.

```
<script runat="server" language="JScript" src="json2.js">
<script runat="server" language="JScript">

function httpGet(url) {
  var objHTTP = Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP");
  objHTTP.open("GET", url, false);

  objHTTP.setRequestHeader("CustomerAccountId", "{my_account_id}");
  objHTTP.setRequestHeader("CustomerId", "{my_customer_id}");
  objHTTP.setRequestHeader("DeveloperToken", "{my_API_access_Key}");
  objHTTP.setRequestHeader("Password", "{my_password}");
  objHTTP.setRequestHeader("UserName", "{my_user_name}");
  objHTTP.send();

  // Error treatment
  if (objHTTP.Status >= 400 && objHTTP.Status <= 599) {
    Response.write("Error Occurred : " + objHTTP.status + " - " + objHTTP.statusText);
     Response.end();
  }
  return objHTTP;
}

var xhr = httpGet("http://localhost/website/api.asp");
var data = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);

// read about how to access objects and arrays in JS
</script>
```

You can even mix VBScript and Javascript on the same page.

```
<script runat="server" language="VBScript">
Function HttpGet(url)
    Set objHTTP = Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")

    With objHTTP
        .open "GET", url, False

        'Some headers:
        .setRequestHeader "CustomerAccountId", "{my_account_id}" 
        .setRequestHeader "CustomerId", "{my_customer_id}"
        .setRequestHeader "DeveloperToken", "{my_API_access_Key}"
        .setRequestHeader "Password", "{my_password}"
        .setRequestHeader "UserName", "{my_user_name}"
        .send ""

        'Error treatment:
        If .Status >= 400 And .Status <= 599 Then
           Response.write "Error Occurred : " & .status & " - " & .statusText
           Response.end
        End If
    End With

    Set HttpGet = objHTTP
End Function
</script>

<script runat="server" language="JScript" src="json2.js">
<script runat="server" language="JScript">
var xhr = HttpGet("http://localhost/website/api.asp");
var data = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);

// read about how to access objects and arrays in JS
</script>
```

I am not showing how to work with objects in JS. For one thing, I don't know your object structure. For another, this is basic stuff you can read about absolutely everywhere.